# Boost 1.59.0 how do I clean the project?

Tags: c++, boost

I built the project once, so it generated a bunch of .o and .a files.  Now, I am trying to clean it.

This page: http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html tells me that `b2 --clean-all` or `b2 clean` should work.

However, I tried:

```
  b2 clean
  b2 --clean
  b2 --clean-all
```

None of them seem to do anything.  How do I clean the boost workspace?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If use -n together with --clean-all, to report the commands it would run, like:

```
b2 --clean-all -n
```

Then I do see things cleaned as usual. Same with --clean. Maybe, you're confused by the fact that configuration is printed even with --clean? That's expected, since the things to build and clean depend on configuration tests.

Comment: interesting.  i tried that, and it's executing "rm", but not in the right locations.  I also re-configured the jam file to use a cross compiler toolchain.  Must be an error in my jam file or something.

Comment: make sure that you pass the same properties when running --clean. Say, if you did "b2 variant=release" followed by "b2 --clean variant=debug", it will try to clean whatever debug build would have created, not what release build has created.

Answer (score 5):

I usually build with `--build-dir=/tmp/build-boost`. On my system /tmp/ is mounted as `tmpfs` (so that when I reboot, the temporary files are gone anyways).

For this reason, I wager, you could simply look at the default value for `--build-dir` and remove that folder:

```
  --build-dir=DIR         Build in this location instead of building within
                          the distribution tree. Recommended!
```

Regardless of this, cleaning is not required for consistent (re)builds.

A simple trial run shows that the temporaries are created in `./bin.v2/libs/` (at least on my box). You can see for yourself e.g.

```
ommon.mkdir bin.v2/libs/filesystem
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2/release
common.mkdir bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2/release/threading-multi
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2/release/threading-multi/codecvt_error_category.o
```

**Notes**

- `--clean-all` *did* remove those object files for me
- using `--build-dir=/somewhere/else` indeed didn't create these object files in-tree (but still creates `stage/lib/` obviously):

  ```
  common.mkdir /somewhere/else/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem
  common.mkdir /somewhere/else/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build
  common.mkdir /somewhere/else/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2
  common.mkdir /somewhere/else/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2/release
  common.mkdir /somewhere/else/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2/release/threading-multi
  gcc.compile.c++ /somewhere/else/boost/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-4.9.2/release/threading-multi/codecvt_error_category.o
  ```